# Is there a newer version than "2013 experience version will be used" when creating a new site collection inside offcie 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, site-collection, administration

I am working on a new site collection inside office 365. now when i select to create a new private site collection , i got this dialog:-

[image]

where it mentioned that the "Template Selection" will be "2013 experience version will be used".. now as for July 2017, can i have the 2016 experience inside my office site collection? or as for July 2017 the only experience we have is 2013 for our office 365 site collections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

v15 is the current version for 'site experience'. For example, in SharePoint Server 2016, a fork of SharePoint Online, sites are in 'v15' mode. Microsoft purposefully did not go to a v16 mode to preserve site/site template compatibility and prevent the costly upgrade process that was traditionally found between versions of SharePoint when site customizations were in place.